# What is the equivalent of innerHTML in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sorting li through an array. I have figured out a working way with innerHTML, but I dont want to use innerHTML, how can I fix this without innerhtml? It works fine by now, I just want to use something else instead of .innerHTML. jQuery solution would be ideal!

```
ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("LI");

a.sort();//array that needs to be sorted 

for(var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
{ 
    lis[i].innerHTML = a[i][0]+" "+a[i][1];
}
```

I want to change the `lis[i].innerHTML` to something else in jQuery.

Comment: `I just want to use something else instead of .innerHTML` Why that??? Now see jQuery `html()` method but doesn't really make sense here

Comment: There is [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) and [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) & [`createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode) depending on your needs and browser support, without the use of jQuery.

Comment: You can use `.text()` method in jQuery. This will only get the text inside the tags.

Comment: What are contents of array `a` ?

Comment: I simply forgot to put paranthesis when I tried with jQuery, thats why it didn't work... now it works! Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

`.html` in JQuery

```
$(lis[i]).html("this is how i work in jQuery");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$( "div.demo-container" ).html("your html");`

See : [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score 0):

change

```
lis[i].innerHTML = a[i][0]+" "+a[i][1]
```

to

```
$(lis[i]).html(a[i][0]+" "+a[i][1])
```

to jQuerify it